# Complex date range extraction from json using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to extract all the dates after *2019-10-21* till today from the below json response using python. I'm very new to Python and just beginning to explore new functions. Can anyone give me a hint to start with?

*my api response*

```
response=
{ "id": "100", 
"location":
{
"address1" : {"city":"x", "state":"y", "zip":"55"}, 
"address2" : {"city":"g", "state":"h", "zip":"33"},
},
"date": [
{
 "shipping_date": "2020-12-13",
 "shipping_name": "xuv"
},
{
 "shipping_date": "2014-11-31",
 "shipping_name": "yuv"
},
{
 "shipping_date": "2020-12-14",
 "shipping_name": "puv"
},
{
 "shipping_date": "2020-08-22",
 "shipping_name": "juv"
},
{
 "shipping_date": "2019-10-21",
 "shipping_name": "auv"
} ]
}
```

*my output*

```
id | shipping_date | shipping_name
100| 2020-12-13 | xuv
100| 2020-12-14 | puv
100| 2020-08-22 | juv
```

Comment: I tried doing something using timedelat fun but not getting the right direction to use it. 
sdate= ( 2019, 10, 21) , edate= ( 2020, 12, 17) , but how to incorporate these date ranges inside a for loop especially when it's inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for data in response["date"]:
    print(data["shipping_date"])
```

Use this code to get all the shipping date.

Comment: I don't need all the dates, i need only between a specific date range, like here i need all dates from 2019 till 2020

Comment: Then follow the link to convert string into datetime object and compare year,month and day attributes.[Convert String to DateTime Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 0):

*Building upon Sagun Devkota's answer as OP asked for data between specific date ranges.*
You can use `time.strptime` to parse and compare dates.
Suppose you need everything from **1-1-2019** to **31-12-2020**, you can do,

```py
import time
start = time.strptime("2019-1-1","%Y-%m-%d")
end = time.strptime("2020-12-31","%Y-%m-%d")

for data in response["date"]:
    date = time.strptime(data["shipping_date"],"%Y-%m-%d")
    if date>=start and date<=end:
        print(data["shipping_date"])
```

PS: November has 30 days while the `shipping_date` at index `1` is `11-31`.